# Sharepoint ListItem-Permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-list

I'm developing a sharepoint 2010 application. One Part of these application is a List of items.

ListCollumns: Title, Owner1, Owner2

The user should be able to create ListItems and to set the items owners (Owner1, Owner2). After creating the item, only the owners and the Administrators should be able to change it.

My ideas:

1. working with a **event receiver** that deletes all permissions on the new item after creating it and setting new permissions to Owner1 and Owner2 (Problems I expect: I'm working in a Sandboxsolution and I think I can't set permissions in it)
2. Creating a **timejob** which execute a powershell everyday. The powershell will delete and create the permissions (Problem: I think the script needs high permissions and it isn't exact if it just run one time per day)

**my question is:** does any one have an idea how to solve the problems or if there are different solutions how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what you describe using an Event Receiver a couple times before. It worked great. Each time, the Event Receiver was part of a farm solution. But it should work in a sandbox solution as everything you need is marked as "Available in Sandboxed Solutions: Yes"

- [SPListItem.BreakRoleInheritance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.breakroleinheritance.aspx)
- [SPSecurableObject.RoleAssignments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.roleassignments.aspx)
- [SPRoleAssignmentCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464302.aspx)
- [SPRoleAssignment Class](http://SPRoleAssignment%20Class)

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint Designer with SPD Activities custom actions, you can set the permissions with a workflow that fires after the item is created: [Link](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grant%20Permission%20on%20Item&ProjectName=spdactivities)

Comment: It looks quiet well, but it is only avaliable for sharepoint 2007.